# Last <li> goes to new row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a landing page but I'm struggling to make my navigation bar work. Basically, it's supposed to put all the anchors in one row with an equal padding (Since I have 4: 25%) but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/hLeytf6u/

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: auto;
  float: left;
}

.navbar h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25%;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of using padding-right, use width. when using padding-right, the padding is added to the overall width of the list item, which also includes the text width itself.

Comment: using `flex` and `justify-content: space-between` http://jsfiddle.net/9h0eo6nc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the rows using flexbox.

Simply change in your css the following:

```
.navbar ul {
  //your styles here
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: block;
  //rest of your styles
}
```

Updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLeytf6u/1/

Answer (score 3):

It's because the padding is added on to the width of the item, so all of your paddings add up to 100% of the width, but then the width of the actual content of each LI makes it over 100% so it has to wrap.

If you change it from padding-right: 25% to width: 25% you'll see it will start to work.

I'd seriously look into flex for layouts like this though, it's far far simpler.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I dont know why question author chose different post as an answer when it does not include explanation and proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: 25%;` instead of padding, as has been said in the comments. You also might want to add `box-sizing: border-box` to include whatever borders or padding you have * into*  that `width`, and you might want to use `text-align: center;` to better distribute the `li`  contents/text across the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/45e9mpsL/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` for ul style. You don't need `padding` anymore.

With the use of `display:flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` on `ul` style you will achieve desired result.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: auto;
  float: left;
}

.navbar h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/jy2aokug/) as well.